# How to convert date to Year.Q fomat in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

```
   2000-01   2000-02   2000-03   2000 -04 ......   2016-08
0    1010       43453      5564       45545           15555
1    4565       44646      8989       56565           56565
```

I have a dataframe like this.I need to add some columns like "2000q1" which means the mean values of 2000-01,2000-02,2000-03. So month 4-6 is q2 ,month 7-9 is q3 ,month 10-12 is q4.
I think the result should be like this:

```
2000q1       2000q2    2000q3   2000q4  2001q1......2016q3
16675.67     15615     ...................................
19400        55665     ...................................
```

I think the first step is to convert the columns to datetime.

```
import pandas as pd
df.columns.map(pd.to_datetime)
```

But I don't know what's the next step

---

I have an idea but it doesn't work.
I use the loop.

```
d = []
for i in range(2000,2017):
    i=str(i)
    d.append(i+'q'+str(1))
    d.append(i+'q'+str(2))
    d.append(i+'q'+str(3))
    d.append(i+'q'+str(4))
#I create a list contains the date I need. Next step is put mean values in.
d = d[:-1] #remove 2016q4 from list because the date untill 2016-08
for date in d:
    for a in range(0,201,3):
        average = np.mean(df.iloc[:,a:a+3])
        df[date] = average
```

But the result shows that the new columns are all NaN values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the column headers to `datetime` and then `to_period` of Quarters, group by the columns names and calculate the average along the row direction:

*Example*:

```
import pandas as pd

df
#2000-01  2000-02  2000-03  2000-04
#0  1010    43453     5564    45545
#1  4565    44646     8989    56565

df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns, format="%Y-%m").to_period("Q")    
df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).mean()

#         2000Q1     2000Q2
#0  16675.666667    45545.0
#1  19400.000000    56565.0
```

Comment: It works. BTW, how can I learn pandas? If I didn't face this problem,  I will never know the to_period fuction...